# Bake Depth / Displacement in Blender 3.0 and up

Tags: texture-baking, shader-nodes

In Blender 2.79, I can bake from high poly to low poly mesh easily using Displacement option and changing distance.

In Blender 3.0, the only node I can see that should work is Camera Data - Z depth. It works fine in renders but not bake.

An example of what I got in 2.79:

[image: Wire].

[image: Chain]